# drupal pager with form data

Tags: forms, drupal, pager

I have a form that obviously takes in some elements and then runs a select against an external database. I can present the data back without issue. What I'm having trouble with is getting the pager to submit correctly. the initial request to pager_query() is good and displays back the content and pager correctly. However, when i select the pager link, the pager simply rebuilds the form and does not submit. I see the GET request get added to the url at the top but that's it. I have to then manually submit the form for the pager to work correctly. Has anyone seen this happen? I tried to write some ajax to hijack the request and submit a GET but still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of pit-falls when using Drupal pagers. The first is that if you have several pager_query()'s on a single page, then every 'pager' element on the page willby default only reference the first query. So the first thing you should do is check you aren't using multiple pager_queries to different databases. If you are using Drupal 7.0, then this is what a properly formed pager query should look like:

```
$query = db_select('node','n')->extend('PagerDefault');
$query->limit(10);
$query->fields('n',array('nid',))
$query->orderBy('n.nid','DESC');
```

If you manage to find duplicate pager queries, then you can set which pager query to reference by using:

```
$pager = array(
  'tags' => array(),
  'element' => 1, /* 0 for first query on the page, 1 for second etc. */
  'quantity' => 5,
  'parameters' => array(),
);

$form['table'] = array(
        '#markup' => theme_table($variables) . theme_pager($pager),
);
```

If you are using Drupal 6, then the solution might be slightly different.